# Custom Post Status 404 URL

Tags: php

I have a function that expires posts after a certain amount of time. It also sets a custom post status of `'expired'`. I would like it to function like a `'draft'` post in that the URL is no longer accessible to the public. At the moment, once the post is set to `'expired'`, the full permalink is still visible. Here is my code:

```
function hrl_custom_status_creation(){
    register_post_status( 'expired', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Expired', 'post_type_listings' ),
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'protected' => true,
        '_builtin'  => true
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'hrl_custom_status_creation' );

// change post status to 'expired'
                $postdata = array(
                    'ID'          => $post_id,
                    'post_status' => 'expired',
                );  

// Update post data
wp_update_post($postdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

`'public'                    => true,`

change to

`'public'                    => false,`

Answer (score -1):

this function changes the post to draft, you only have to call it and pass the post id where you want the function to work

```php
function postToDraft($post_id){
    $post = array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
    wp_update_post($post);
}
```

Comment: I would like my custom post status to mimic the draft status, not actually change it to draft. Is this possible?